# JavaFX Calculator - How do I add a square and square root function?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a JavaFX Calculator. I am trying to develop a square and square root function, but I'm puzzled what to write in Controller.java for the method. I'm not sure if they're even working right, if I click them they return nothing. I think, "okay, is the value stored?" I attempt to add 0 to it to see if there's a result, and errors.

App.java:

```
package com.honors.calc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

Model.java:

```
package com.honors.calc;

public class Model {

    public long calculate(long number1, long number2, String operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                return number1 + number2;
            case "-":
                return number1 - number2;
            case "*":
                return number1 * number2;
            case "/":
                if (number2 == 0)
                    return 0;

                return number1 / number2;
            case "C":
                number1 = 0;
                number2 = 0;
                return 0;
            case "CE":
                number2 = 0;
                return 0;
            case "x²":
                return number1 * number1;
            case "√":
                return (long) Math.sqrt(number1);
        }
        System.out.println("Unknown operator - " + operator);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
package com.honors.calc;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Text output;

    private long number1 = 0;
    private String operator = "";
    private boolean start = true;

    private Model model = new Model();

    @FXML
    private void processNumpad(ActionEvent event) {
        if (start) {
            // clear screen
            output.setText("");
            start = false;
        }
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
        output.setText(output.getText() + value);
    }

    @FXML
    private void processOperator(ActionEvent event) {
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();

        if(!"=".equals(value)) {
            if (!operator.isEmpty())
                return;

            operator = value;
            number1 = Long.parseLong(output.getText());
            output.setText("");
        } else {
            // calculation
            if (operator.isEmpty())
                return;

            output.setText(String.valueOf(model.calculate(number1, Long.parseLong(output.getText()), operator)));
            operator = "";
            // reset
            start = true;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void processClear(ActionEvent event) {
        output.setText("0");
    }

    @FXML
    private void processClearEntry(ActionEvent event) {
        output.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    private void processSquare(ActionEvent event) {


    }

    @FXML
    private void processSquareRoot(ActionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

ui.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.beans.property.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>

<VBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="300" prefHeight="320" fx:controller="com.honors.calc.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <fx:define>
        <Font fx:id="FONT" size="18" />
    </fx:define>

    <StackPane alignment="CENTER">
        <Rectangle fill="TRANSPARENT" stroke="GRAY" width="230" height="50" />
        <Text fx:id="output" font="$FONT" />
    </StackPane>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="C" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processClear" />
        <Button text="CE" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processClearEntry" />
        <Button text="x²" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processSquare" />
        <Button text="√" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processSquareRoot" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="7" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="8" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="9" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="/" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="4" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="5" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="6" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="*" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="1" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="2" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="3" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="-" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="0" prefWidth="110" font="$FONT" onAction="#processNumpad" />
        <Button text="=" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
        <Button text="+" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
    </HBox>

</VBox>
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to do anything? The `processSquare` and `processSquareRoot` functions are completely empty.

Comment: @jewelsea I think I have the syntax defined in Model.java `case "x²":
                return number1 * number1;
            case "√":
                return (long) Math.sqrt(number1);` but the thing is I'm not sure what to put in the method. For the other methods I put `output.setText("");` but that doesn't seem like the right thing to put in `processSquare` and `processSquareRoot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue stems from an un-handled [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) here:

```
output.setText(String.valueOf(model.calculate(number1, Long.parseLong(output.getText()), operator)));
```

As your design requires an equals to initiate the actual calculation, it also assumes a second number will be present. So this is recreate-able with the following input:

> 5 x² = (as a second value isn't provided, an empty String is being parsed for the second value)

A **quick fix** for this would be to replace that line with the following:

```
        long number2 = 0;
        try{
            number2 = Long.parseLong(output.getText());
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println("Invalid value provided for second value");
        }
        output.setText(String.valueOf(model.calculate(number1, number2, operator)));
```

and update your fxml:

```
<Button text="x²" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
<Button text="√" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#processOperator" />
```

This would remove the need for these methods:

```
    @FXML
    private void processSquare(ActionEvent event) {    
    }

    @FXML
    private void processSquareRoot(ActionEvent event) {    
    }
```

As even if you were to implement them, they wouldn't be able to calculate the values without improving your underlying design as the operation and number(s) needed are only used within your `processOperator` method

---

As a side note, I would recommend reading up on the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It is used to parse infix notation equations into their postfix equivalents allowing for easy calculation. Having personally used it in the past to create a custom Scientific calculator, it would allow you to add additional functionality to your own calculator. The main benefit for your implementation would be the ability to enter more complex equations with additional operators.

Even if you don't end up using it, it's an interesting algorithm to know / be aware of